# subquery in a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

How do I create subquery in another subquery?

This is what I got, obviously it doesn't work:

```
"Select `region` from `region` where `regioncode` IN 
        (Select `city` from `city` where `citycode` IN 
                (Select `citycode` from `postcode` where `postcode` LIKE '%" + txtPostcode.Text + "%'))"
```

Sorry for my amateur questions by the way.

Tabel structure:

Tabel region:

```
regioncode  region      provincecode    netnumber
```

Tabel city:

```
citycode    city    from    to  regioncode
```

"from" and "to" imply the postcode range of the city.

Tabel postcode:

```
postcode    street  from    to  citycode
```

Here "from" and "to" implies the range of the adress numbers

Tabel province:

```
provincecode    province
```

So, I should be able to get the region from where the postal code comes from. The postal code will be entered from a textbox.

I got the street, city and adress number range. But the region doesn't work for me.

Also sorry for my broken English, and my amateur questions :.

Comment: More information would help, what you mean by "doesn't work" and descriptions of your table structures.

Comment: Your subquery syntax itself is pretty much right but the rest of the query does not make sense  Select 'province' from 'province'?? What database are you querying?

Comment: In the city subquery shouldn't it be `select provincecode from city...`

Comment: @OTTA I'll set the table structure in the OP in 1 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using [JOINs](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) instead of multiple subqueries.

```
SELECT region from region r
JOIN city c ON c.regioncode = r.regioncode
JOIN postcode pc ON pc.citycode = c.citycode
WHERE pc.postcode LIKE '%test%'
```

This would be the equivalent of what you're currently trying to do with subqueries.

**EDIT**: I've updated the query above to not go through province since it's not needed if city has a regioncode and you're just trying to get region.  You could still use subqueries.  You should just be getting `regioncode` from the `city` table instead of `city`:

```
SELECT region FROM region WHERE regioncode IN 
    (SELECT regioncode FROM city WHERE citycode IN 
        (SELECT citycode FROM postcode WHERE postcode LIKE '%test%')
    )
```

I'm just using `test` as a temp value for whatever would be in txtPostcode.Text

Comment: I added the tables and column names to my original post, also my apologies. I messed it up, it was supposed to be region and region code instead of province.